# ivy build - multiple artifacts of different versions

Tags: java, ivy

We recently started using ant-ivy for a java webapp and the journey has been good so far. I have specified transitive='false' for all dependencies and listed log4j version 1.2.16 as a dependency. I have to use a recent version of log4j as I rely on an enhanced pattern layout.

Main problem - when the project is built, there are multiple versions of log4j in the ivy-lib folder. When looking at the package explorer in Eclipse, I see the right version and seems like it downloads only 1.2.16 from ivycachepath.

Any pointers? Do I need to remove each dependency individually and see which one brings older versions?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you perhaps demonstrate what your build file looks like. Couple of things puzzle me. For example what do you mean by "ivy-lib"? Secondly turning off transitive dependencies is your right, however you'll be losing one of the main benefits of using dependency management.

Comment: do you delete/clear the lib folder before each resolve? Ivy does not delete old artifacts unless you specify **sync="true"** to the retrieve task.

Answer (score 1):

I've included an example ant build which downloads log4j as a dependency, into a local directory called "lib".

```
$ ant
$ find lib
lib
lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar
```

As you can see only one version of the jar is present. Hope this helps in diagnosing your issue.

## build.xml

```
<project xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" name="hello-ivy" default="retrieve">

    <property name="lib.dir" location="lib"/>
    <property name="report.dir" location="report"/>

    <target name="retrieve" description="Retrieve dependencies locally">
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib.dir}/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>

        <ivy:report todir="${report.dir}" graph="false"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean" description="Remove build directories">
        <delete dir="${lib.dir}"/>
        <delete dir="${report.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-all" depends="clean" description="clean ivy cache">
        <ivy:cleancache />
    </target>

</project>
```

## ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="org.demo" module="demo"/>

    <configurations defaultconfmapping="compile->default">
        <conf name="compile" description="jars used for compilation"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.16"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```